# Feign Oauth how to manually set the bearer token value?

Tags: oauth, swagger-codegen, feign

I'm developping a Rest API, MyApi.
In there, I'm using Feign (and swagger codegen) to generate a client  for another API, let's call it Ext-API.

The user will have called Ext-API previously and among other things will have retrieved a JWT Token.
He'll then call my API using Basic Auth and in the body it'll give me the JWT token.

I'm to use this JWT token as auth header to connect to Ext-API from my API and do some more stuff on behalf of the user.

However all example of Oauth & Feign example rely on the Oauth also being used to connect to the API using the generated client.

I can't find how I could, on every request, update the Oauth Token.
There are nothing exposed by feign to do this.
Atm I'm using regular Rest template.

Answer (score 1):

You can used @RequestHeader in feign Client, see below

```
@FeignClient(name = "<name>", configuration = <configclass>)
public interface Client {

    public final String AUTH_TOKEN = "Authorization";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "users", produces = "application/json")
    public HttpEntity<List<User>> getUsers(@RequestHeader(AUTH_TOKEN) String oruToken,
            @RequestParam("<param>") Integer value);
}
```

and from you program you can pass token to feign client

Comment: Thanks that would work.
However I'm using Maven codegen with feign to generate the client, thus I cannot edit the way the WS method is declared in the interface to add an extra header.
I was looking for a way to inject request specific header.

Comment: Saw there is an issue opened since a while about this : https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/214